# Silverlight pdf printing broken with last release?

Tags: windows, printing

We use a Silverlight OOB application that prints orders and invoices, usually writing them to disk as a pdf with utilities such as dopdf.

Recently this stopped working. All virtual printer drivers that access the disk report an access violation - even if the directory is fully accessible by "everyone".

I suspect this to have something to do with the latest Silverlight Release 5.1.40416.0 from May, 12 this year - because I know it used to work and Microsoft's release history talks about "Vulnerability in Silverlight Could Allow Elevation of Privilege".

EDIT: There is another symptom unrelated to printing. It used to be possible to open mail programs by clicking on mailto-Hyperlinkbuttons. That too, has since become broken except in the circumstances named in my answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't get it. How am I not stating what my original problem is? And how would you know even if that's the case? Clearly you'd need to know what *other* original problem I would then need to have had.

Comment: Your problem appears to be: "All virtual printer drivers that access the disk report an access violation". How you got from there to suspecting a Silverlight security update is not at all clear. Have you actually investigated the access violation issue? At the moment, it reads like you just made a wild guess with no evidence. And, if it is the case that this is _not_ the cause of the problem, you are no closer to finding an actual solution.

Comment: Does the directory referenced by `%temp%\low` exist and have the correct permissions in each user's profile directory? (usually expands to something like `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Low\`).

Comment: @Brian Exists and my user has full access. Also, the same drivers work when not printing from Silverlight.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The same drivers work as expected when not printing from the Silverlight app. Also, I'm not the only one having this problem. The currently only other user also can't print into a pdf or xps with this SL app.

Answer (score 0):

I found workarounds:

I can print with the exact same SL app if either

- I don't run it out of browser, but in-browser, or
- I run it out of browser, but with elevated privileges.

In both cases the permission problem on saving the pdf to disk from the printer driver dialog does not occur.

This behavior has definitely changes recently, and I would guess it was brought with the recent update. In my case, we can live with either of those solutions.